# Cannot install Microsoft Office 2010 using PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I am trying to install Microsoft Office 2010 on Ubuntu 14.04 using PlayOnLinux and I selected office 2010 from the list of programs to install on PlayOnLinux. I was fine selecting the .exe setup file for office but after I got the office popup and could install office from there but after i clicked the close button on the installer PlayOnLinux still has a loading icon saying 'Please wait while Microsoft Office 2010 is installing'
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Check in your task manager whether there is still an instance of the installer running (search for anything with `.exe` in it). If you find something related, kill it. POL may report that it crashed, then you hit continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime the Windows installers called by PlayOnLinux don't quit properly.

To continue the installation, open your task manager (most likely gnome-system-monitor) and kill all remaining instances of the installer. Just search for anything related to your Windows program with `.exe` in the taskname. Kill all remaining installer processes.

Afterwards, PlayOnLinux may say that some error occurred. Ignore this and click *Continue*. Your installation should finish as intended.